# Jquery select div inside ul which has a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Take the following code:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="section">
        <span class="show">ABC</span>
        <ul class="items"><li>UL selected</li></ul>
    </li>
     <li class="section">
        <span class="">DEF</span>
        <ul class="items"><li>UL not selected</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to select each ul.items inside a li.section which has a span with class "show". In this example, only the first ul.items should be selected.

What jquery selector do I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could do the trick (http://jsfiddle.net/bmqyF/1/):

`$("ul li.section:has(span.show) ul.items li");`

Comment: Thank you! JSFiddle is a nice tip as well! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li.section:has(span.show) ul.items')
```

Finds the `li.section`'s that have `span.show` and selects the `ul.items` within it.